# "How accurate" vs "How accurately"

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

Which one is right?

> We use our algorithm to evaluate how **accurately** it is possible to
>   model protein  structures with dihedral angles.

or

> We use our algorithm to evaluate how **accurate** it is possible to
>   model protein  structures with dihedral angles.

I am inclined to the second sentence. Is there a rule for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (accurately) as an **adverb**, which means "a word that describes a verb", ie that describes how a something is being done.

The second (accurate) is an **adjective**, which means "a word that describes a noun", ie that describes a "thing" rather than an action.

So, what is being described by accurate/accurately in this case?  It's the **modelling** of protein structures.  This is a **verb**, ie "to model".  So, we're describing a verb, so **we want an adverb rather than an adjective**, ie "accurately".

That's the rule.

If we were talking about the model, rather than the process of modelling (ie a noun rather than a verb) we'd use the adjective, eg "How accurate is our model?"

Comment: Thanks @Max for your answer. Just a follow up question, why do we say "It is nice to see you" and not " ..nicely..."?

Comment: Because "nice" isn't describing the **way we see someone**.  It's describing the **experience** of seeing them, which is a noun.